# Solidify Modifier behaving strangely

Tags: modifiers

When I apply the "Solidify" modifier to my object, this one window I have acts differently then all of the others. They all look okay, but this one gets messed up by the modifier.

Here are 2 angles of the messed up part of the mesh with the solidify modifier:

[image: Broken Mesh]
[image: Broken Mesh 2nd angle]

Here is the mesh without the solidify modifier:

[image: working mesh]

And here are my Solidify Modifier settings:

[image: Solidify Modifier Settings]

I got the window pains by extruding the edges out. I have already tried removing overlapping vertices and the scale is applied. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think your normals aren't facing in the same direction.

Comment: Thanks! this worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solidify a fairly complex shape that requires you to change the **Mode** from **Simple** to **Complex** in the modifier's panel.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. After I change it to Complex, are there any settings I need to mess with?

Comment: You are welcome. For your kind of shape I suggest "Thickness Mode = Even", the rest I think you can safely keep as it is. Cheers!

Comment: Also offset to zero, probably.